# Convert binary string to hexadecimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, binary, hex

What is the most efficient way to convert a binary string into hexadecimal? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
a = '1010'    #Binary
```

and then to become

```
a = 'A'       #Hexa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert it to an integer first, hinting that the string is binary (`to_i(2)`), then to hexadecimal (`to_s(16)`

```
"1010".to_i(2).to_s(16) # => 'a'
```

If you need it in uppercase, you can call `upcase` on the resulting string.

Comment: `to_i(2)` doesn't convert to decimal. It converts to an integer. Integers aren't decimal or binary or hexadecimal, they just *are*. Only string interpretations of numbers have a base, numbers themselves don't.

Comment: @JörgWMittag clarified the answer. WDYT?